# How to generate the call when the phone is locked?

Tags: android, service, background

I am running some code in background by using service in my android application. I want to generate a call through my application after 1 minute when application is in background. The call is generating when phone is unlocked but it is not generate when phone is locked. How to achieve this?

Comment: Make sure your service is running when your screen is off by displaying message in the logcat.

Comment: Yes my service is running when screen is off.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check the phone state by this:

```
DevicePolicyManager dpm = (DevicePolicyManager) 
context.getSystemService(Context.DEVICE_POLICY_SERVICE);  
 dpm.lockNow();
```

and then use timer when time is completed launch call:

```
             Intent callIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_CALL);
             callIntent.setData(Uri.parse("tel:" + PhoneNO));
             callIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
            if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(SubscribersDetail.this, Manifest.permission.CALL_PHONE) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                // TODO: Consider calling
                //    ActivityCompat#requestPermissions
                // here to request the missing permissions, and then overriding
                //   public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, String[] permissions,
                //                                          int[] grantResults)
                // to handle the case where the user grants the permission. See the documentation
                // for ActivityCompat#requestPermissions for more details.
                return;
            }
            startActivity(callIntent);
```

Also check this :
http://chandan-tech.blogspot.in/2010/10/handling-screen-lock-unlock-in-android.html